# Contact Form 7 works only on https, otherwise spinning

Tags: php, wordpress, contacts

Contact Form 7 works only if I add https:// before my domain. If i access it with www.example.com withot 'https://' before, after I submit the form I get only spinning wheel and not sending the mail.

In inspector it says: "`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`".

I just transfered wordpress website from local to the server.

Also, my base is all set to https://www.example.com. I tried changing everything in DB to www.example.com and it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You could just force https on your entire website.

Answer (score 1):

Changed everything https://www.example.com to http://www.example.com and boom. Now it works on both sides.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you try to submit from the http side then you're probably finding that the submit goes to a http form handler.  From there it redirects to the https version of the form handler, however the redirect doesn't pass on the POST variables so the handler never receives any data and doesn't send the email.  Set your entire site to HTTPS and use HSTS as well.